# Best way to make send bulk emails parallel

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I am new to TPL (Task Parallel Library) and I'm having a hard time trying to configure my process to run tasks in parallel.

I'm working on an application to send bulk emails (like thousands per minute, that's the idea), but when I see the processors performance, it's not good: **I'm pretty sure there's a lot of overhead cause I'm not using the Task library properly**.

Here's my code:

```
public async void MainProcess()
{
    var batches = emailsToProcess.Batch(CONST_BATCHES_SIZE);
    
    foreach (var batch in batches.AsParallel()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount))
    {
         await Task.WhenAll(from emailToProcess in batch 
                    select ProcessSingleEmail(emailToProcess));
        _emailsToProcessRepository.MarkBatchAsProcessed(batch);
    }
}

private async Task ProcessSingleEmail(EmailToProcess emailToProcess)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = GetMail(emailToProcess); //static light method
        await _smtpClient.SendAsync(sendGridMail);
        emailToProcess.Processed = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Error(ErrorHelper.GetExceptionMessage(e, 
                    string.Format("Error sending Email ID #{0} : ", 
                    emailToProcess.Id)), e);
    }
}
```

*(I know it might look awful: please feel free to roast me ☺)*

I need it to behave this way: I need to process a number of records in a batch (btw, I'm using a library that allows me to use the "Batch" method), cause I need to mark a batch of records as processed in the database as the process completes sending them.

The process is actually doing what I want: except is **slow as hell**. And as you can see in the perfmon, the processors are not working at a very high capacity:

[image]

What's the best way to do this? Any advice?

**EDIT:** I realize that what I have is an overhead problem.
Is there any tool or easy way to detect and correct them?

Comment: I expect that the limiting factor is your network bandwidth, not your CPU... parallelize your CPUs all you want, it will not give you a faster network connection.

Comment: @abelenky Thanks for your response, but I don't think that's the issue. I even tried replacing the SendAsync with a Task.Delay(1500), which is approximately what it takes to send an email, and the result was exactly the same.

Comment: of course your network is the limiting factor here - but I think you can do more than `.WithDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)` here because you are trying to be async (experiment a bit) - aside from this you might have to try out alternatives to the frameworks Smtpclient ... btw: what kind of bulk email is this going to be? We have enough spam around ;)

Comment: haha, thanks @CarstenKönig, it won't be spam, just a small "linkedin" alerts-like website. I don't think the network is the issue cause I tried mocking the smtpclient with a Task.Delay meaning that no other network required operation is invoked and the result was the same. Good observation, I'm not using an SmtpClient but the Sendgrid api which uses http.

Comment: No you said you *mocked* it with a Task.Delay of 1.5seconds and got the same result (which proofes nothing) - so if your sending does take 1.5sec. (the bits of your code you have no control over) than obvious there is the place to start looking (you can crank up the number of parallel tasks as I said - but 1500ms is huge!)

Comment: Try materializing your `IEnumerable` inside `await Task.WhenAll` by calling `ToList`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are doing is not CPU bound but I/O bound so using limiting the number of concurrent tasks to the number if processors is likely impacting your performance. Try starting more tasks in parallel.

For example the code below will process all emails asynchronously but limit to 100 emails in parallel. It uses a `ForEachAsync` extension method to do the processing, the method allows to limit the degree of parallelism with a parameter so I would try and experiment with making that parameter larger.

You may also want to make the `MarkBatchAsProcessed` method asynchronous if possible as that is likely to limit performance as well.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static async Task ExecuteInPartition<T>(IEnumerator<T> partition, Func<T, Task> body)
    {
        using (partition)
            while (partition.MoveNext())
                await body(partition.Current);
    }

    public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body)
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(
            from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
            select ExecuteInPartition(partition, body));
    }
}

public Task MainProcess()
{
    // Process 100 emails at a time
    return emailsToProcess.ForEachAsync(100, async (m) =>
    {
        await ProcessSingleEmail(m);                
    });

    _emailsToProcessRepository.MarkBatchAsProcessed(emailsToProcess);
}
```

You should also avoid using `void` returning async methods, they don't propagate exceptions and cannot be composed or awaited and their use is mostly for event handlers, so I changed `MainProcess` to return `Task`.

**Update**

The number 100 in the code above means that at any one time there will be a maximum of 100 concurrent tasks, so it's more like a sliding window rather than a batch. If you wanted to process the emails in batches, you can do something like this(assuming batches have a Count property:

```
public async Task MainProcess()
{
    var batches = emailsToProcess.Batch(CONST_BATCHES_SIZE);

    foreach (var batch in batches)
    {
         return batch.ForEachAsync(batch.Count, async (m) =>
         {
             await ProcessSingleEmail(m);                
         });

       _emailsToProcessRepository.MarkBatchAsProcessed(batch);             
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ned-stoyanov for taking the time to show me this approach!!
Just a couple of comments: 
1) I think the 100 means the number of partitions and not the partition size.
2) Where should i update the batch? should i pass it as an action parameter to the same extension method and do it at the end of using(partition)?